# ERROR in ./src/index.js 14:4 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:4) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I am tryiyng to run react with webpack. I am getting following error:

ERROR in ./src/index.js 14:4
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (14:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

```
| ReactDOM.render(
>     <HashRouter>
|         <App />
|     </HashRouter>,
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/App.js'),
    watch: true,
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
        }]
    }, 
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app-weather",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bulma": "^0.7.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.39.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.8.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your babel-loader config:

1. Change your `test` condition to `/\.jsx?$/`, so .jsx will be also transpiled.
2. Add `options` with your `react` preset *under*(!) `use` (*not* as *sibling* to `use`)
3. If you want to use Babel 6, then you need to install [babel-loader v7](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/tree/7.x) (`npm i -D babel-loader@7`) instead of [v8](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader) which is for Babel 7.

Then you should be fine. Here are the relevant parts of configs for Babel 6 (and 7 if you want to change) that worked for me:

#### Babel 6

webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["react"]
          },
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  },
}
```

#### Babel 7

webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6"
  }
}
```

Hope, it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the preset for react to be loadable via babel, and add support for JSX files

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/App.js'),
    watch: true,
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/, // change here
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            options: { // added this
                presets: ['react'],
            },
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
            }
        ]
    }, 
}
```

Comment: I added:
- presets: ['react', 'env']
- test: /\.(js|jsx)$
I have the same problem ... same error ...

Answer (score 1):

**It means your browser is serving un-transpiled or un-transformed code.**

This issue comes when somehow those files are left out for the transpilation, please make sure those folders are included in webpack module section under a valid loader, for example - for typescript - ts-loader etc. Spent a lot of hours and got the fix.

You may use another compiler like babel for the same. It's up to you what suits your need.

```js
 module: {
       rules: [
                    {
                        test: /\.ts|\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader', 
                        options: { onlyCompileBundledFiles: true, configFile: "testing.tsconfig.json", compilerOptions: {
                            noEmit: false, allowTsInNodeModules: false
                          }}, 
                        include: [
                            path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
                            path.resolve(__dirname, "./tests")
                          ],
                        exclude: [ 
                            path.resolve(__dirname, './automation/'),
                            path.resolve(__dirname, './src/types/testutils/'),
                            path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/')
                      ]
                    }
            ]
   }
```

Look at this include section:

```js
 include: [
         path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
         path.resolve(__dirname, "./tests")
 ],
```